# iOS Sheet Detents (presentation detents) not working after updating from iOS 15 to iOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-sheet

I recently updated my SwiftUI project from iOS 15.3 to 16.4 (target iPhone only) and wanted to test the new feature of `presentationDetents` [apple developer: presentation detents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationdetents(_:)). It seems that this property is simply ignored. All sheets are shown in full screen manner and are not even resizable.

I tested the sheets in the preview (16.4), the simulator (16.4) and on a real device (iOS 16.5.1). In all cases the detents were ignored.

I created a side project which I initially set up with iOS 16.4 which does not have the issue.

#### Example usage in my main project:

```swift
Text("Foo")
  .sheet(isPresented: $isActive) {
    Text("Sheet Content")
      .presentationDetents([.medium])
  }
```

#### Xcode iOS Target

[image]

My assumption is that something got messed up with the iOS version update.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using .sheet(isPresented: $isActive)?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

After facing another weird bug of nested sheets always automatically closing the entire sheet stack, I figured out that the issue was a circular dependency within my project.

The particular issue was that I used the library `NativePartialSheet` before the updated which still was used in one component. This resulted in an unstable navigation stack state.